# Round checkmark corners with CSS. Is it possible?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend

I've built this simple unordered list that uses checkmarks. The checkmarks dont have any rounded styling to them. Basically wanting to add a border-radius to them, but that wont work in theory. It'll just round the outside of the element. Is it even possible to round the tips of the checkmarks? If there is a way, I dont think using borders would be the right approach? I'm not sure at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
} 

ul li:not(:last-child) {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul li::before{
  content: '';
  display: table;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  height: 12px;
  width: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eb0a1e;
  border-right: 2px solid #eb0a1e;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use two pseudo-elements, one for the small stem, one for the tall one, and make them the same height and give them the same radius. Overlap them at the intersection and you're good to go.

Comment: Try Font-Awesome? they have a wide range of checkmarks and can easily be added to your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea using one element:

```css
.tick {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    background:
      radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right,transparent 97%,green 100%) bottom 19px left 19px/15px 15px content-box padding-box,  
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,green 98%,transparent 100%) top left    /20px 20px,
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,green 98%,transparent 100%) bottom right/20px 20px,
      linear-gradient(green,green) left bottom/20px calc(100% - 10px),
      linear-gradient(green,green) left bottom/calc(100% - 10px) 20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="tick"></div>
```

Where you can consider CSS variable to easily control the shape:

```css
.tick {
    --c:green; /* Color */
    --t:20px;  /* thickness */
    --r:30px;  /* Radius */
    --w:100px; /* width */
    --h:60px;   /* height */
    display: inline-block;
    height: var(--h);
    width: var(--w);
    border-bottom-left-radius: var(--r);
    background:
      radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right,transparent 97%,var(--c) 100%) bottom calc(var(--t) - 0.5px) left calc(var(--t) - 0.5px)/calc(var(--t) * 0.8) calc(var(--t) * 0.8),  
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c) 99%,transparent 100%) top left    /var(--t) var(--t),
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c) 99%,transparent 100%) bottom right/var(--t) var(--t),
      linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) left bottom/var(--t) calc(100% - var(--t)/2),
      linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) left bottom/calc(100% - var(--t)/2) var(--t);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="tick"></div>

<div class="tick" style="--t:10px;--r:20px;--c:red;"></div>

<div class="tick" style="--t:8px;--r:10px;--w:50px;--h:30px;--c:blue;"></div>
```

That you can later place inside your pseudo element:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 18px;
} 

ul li:not(:last-child) {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul li::before {  
     content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 8px;
    --t:9px;
    --r:10px;
    --w:45px;
    --h:25px;
    --c:red;
    height: var(--h);
    width: var(--w);
    border-bottom-left-radius: var(--r);
    background:
      radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right,transparent 97%,var(--c) 100%) bottom calc(var(--t) - 0.5px) left calc(var(--t) - 0.5px)/calc(var(--t) * 0.8) calc(var(--t) * 0.8),  
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c) 99%,transparent 100%) top left    /var(--t) var(--t),
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c) 99%,transparent 100%) bottom right/var(--t) var(--t),
      linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) left bottom/var(--t) calc(100% - var(--t)/2),
      linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) left bottom/calc(100% - var(--t)/2) var(--t);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    transform:rotate(-45deg) scale(0.4);
    transform-origin:left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best checkmark but this is my attempt of using two pseudo to create the checkmarks.

But if I were you, I would look out for a SVG or something like Font-awesome. That would be enough unless you're planning to do some special animation to the checkmarks.

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
}
.list li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.list li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.list li:before, .list li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 4px;
}
.list li:after {
  left: -21px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(-115deg);
  top: 8px;
}
.list li:before {
  left: -17px;
  width: 15px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Overlap two pseudo-elements that are both stems with rounded corners. Place their `transform-origin` at the bottom, minus the radius (try using 100% without the radius to see why).

Here is the functional code, but I took the liberty to use relative units with `em`s instead of `px`s for better scaling, and fewer magic numbers.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 1em;
} 

ul li + li {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

ul li::before,
ul li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: .25em;
  display: table;
  display: inline-block;
  width: .125em;
  border-radius: .125em;
  background: #eb0a1e;
  transform-origin: 50% calc(100% - .0625em);
}

ul li::before {
  height: .875em;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}

ul li::after {
  height: .4375em;
  transform: rotate(-55deg); /* Initially, the group was rotated by -35deg, so the tall stem has been rotated by 35deg, and the small one, which is at a right angle, by 35-90=-55deg */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
```